# Картина - откуда взялось слово?

Tags: этимология

Кажется, слово "художник" тут уже когда-то обсуждалось. А вот меня интересует слово "картина". Есть произведение художника, который рисует, - рисунок. Чертежника, который чертит, - чертеж.
Тогда что есть картина? Она ведь - произведение. Но произведение какого действия?
То же самое, кстати, и со стихами. Стихи пишет поэт, и поэт - понятно, от слова "поэзия". А откуда тогда "стихи"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Картина - от "карта" (бумага) - бумага с изображением. Мы заимствовали в 18 веке из немецкого, они из итальянского. В нем. яз. это была игральная карта и географическая. В итальянском - из латыни - бумага для письма, папирус. Картон - увеличит. форма - толстая бумага. Даже картечь - кулёчек из бумаги.

Comment: заимствовали в XVIII веке

Answer (score 2):

"произведение какого действия?" Правильнее: какого рода.

Писанное не по стене (по стене - фреска), не в размер стены, на другой плоскости и непременно выделенное рамой. Полотно в раме - картина. Не всякий автор картины может считаться художником.

Такая же история со стихами и поэтами.

Answer (score 2):

Являются родственными следующие слова: **карта (игр. и геогр.), картина, картон и даже картечь и хартия.**

Все они восходят к греческому chartes  и латинскому charta (лист бумаги), но пришли в русский язык в разное время:

а) карта (игр.) – 16 век, через польск. от итал. carta;

б)  карта (геогр.) -  из голланд. в Петровское время;

в) картина – от русского «карта» под влиянием итал. cartina  (тонкая, изящная бумага);

г) картон –  начало 18 века. через фр. carton от итал. cartone (плотная бумага).

ВЫВОД:

Рисунок - рисуют, а картины - пишут, картина - это живописное полотно.

Поэт (творец) пишет (творит) стихотворение. Поэзия - творение (от лат. poesis и  греч. poiein - делать, творить, создавать).

Comment: Заимствованные разными путями, тем более - из разных языков, не считаются в языке-приемнике родственными.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, слово "картина" произошло от ит. "cortina" - декоративная драпировка, задник, красивый занавес. В русском языке безударное "о" преобразуется в "а" - морковка, ковыль, моряк, ворошить и т.д. - вот и получилась "кАртина" вместо "кОртина" ...

Comment: Нет, это вульгарная этимология, на чистом созвучии. Во-первых, совершенно не обосновано с этимологической точки зрения, а во-вторых, неверно фонетически. Замена на письме О на А в заимствованных словах - это совершенно невозможно.